# How to run a logger on different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, static

First of all, is this a good idea? Because of IO operations being pretty expensive compared to other operations, I figured that running logger on separate thread should be a good idea. The way I've got it set us is that I have one static, variadic templated function Logger::log(args...) which for every call prints a time stamp on next line and then given arguments as if they were just pushed to a output stream using <<. This is where I would like to use the second thread to just take the parameters and than push them to output on it's own.

Few problems arised when I tried to do this.

If there was one thread created for every call of log wouldn't that mean that calling log multiple times in a row would create a race condition between those threads writing into same file?

So if there was a single thread, the logger has only static members and methods, therefore the thread should also be static?

In this scenario, when using one static thread, I would run a infinite loop function that would poll the log request queue and calling the log function would mean a pushing new log request to that queue. How can this be implemented or is there a better solution?

Here is code example of my logger:

```
class Logger {
public:
    // This is the function you call to log something
    template <typename... T>
    static void log(T&&... args) {
        // I suppose somewhere here I should push the log request to queue
        using namespace date;
        _logStream << floor<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << " - ";
        _log(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }

private:
    // Function that a thread get's when it is created
    static void run() {
        while (true) {
            // Handle que of log calls
        }
    }

    template <typename Th, typename... Tt>
    static void _log(Th&& head, Tt&& ... tail) {
        _logStream << head;
        _log(std::forward<Tt>(tail)...);
    }

    template <typename Th>
    static void _log(Th&& head) {
        _logStream << head << std::endl;
    }

    static std::thread _logThread;
    static std::ofstream _logStream;
};
```

**Edit:** This post ([Is creating a separate thread for a logger ok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725264/is-creating-a-separate-thread-for-a-logger-ok)) doesn't solve my problem, only clarifies some of my questions a bit. Still the answer is how to implement this log queue.

Comment: You'd have to solve the standard producer-consumer problem.  No big deal but it is a bad idea.  The considerable risk is that it won't manage to log critical data that you need to diagnose a crash.  Since the crash can easily wipe out the consumer thread as well before it had a chance to empty the thread-safe queue.  All it takes is a mutex to ensure the output of the log() calls don't get intermingled. The approach taken by all logging libraries afaik, it won't hurt to use one.  At least look at log4cpp.

Comment: The 'goodness' of this idea depends entirely on the requirements of the system. If it's mission-critical that the worker threads operate as fast as possible, and the logging is not required to be flushed as an accurate reflection of the system's history and current state, then this is an excellent idea albeit complex to do well.  A middle ground might be to have the log set up to do async I/O to the log file so that (most of) the complexity of thread management is avoided, but the I/Os do not block the operation of the worker threads. If there's a log library that does that, I'd say use it.

Comment: Given that logging probably spends most of its time waiting for the disk to spin, there should definitely be speed benefit to be had by offloading that disk waiting time to a dedicated thread. As has been pointed out, look up `producer/consumer` patterns for implementation details.